# In OS X, how to power detach screen

Tags: macos, display

I'm not sure what's up here.

I just switched to mac, which I'm liking but I can't seem to power detach my screen sessions

On other unix systems, I do this:

```
screen
[now I'm in a screen session]
[start a process]
[type ctrl-a shift-D]
```

And now the session is detached but the process is still running.

Doesn't seem to be working on my new OS X system...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default shortcut for *power detach* is `C-a D D`. From `man screen`, section `DEFAULT KEY BINDINGS`:

```
   C-a d
   C-a C-d     (detach)      Detach screen from this terminal.

   C-a D D     (pow_detach)  Detach and logout.
```

So you need to repeat the uppercase `D`, or customize your `screen` configuration.

Comment: Ah - I got it.  Thanks.  Trying to live without screen was a pain...